# Interesting "Eulerian" irrational points

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory

Point $(e,\pi)$ on the graph satisfies the famous unifying Euler relation $e^{i\pi}+1=0 $  and we know that these irrational numbers can be individually expressed in power series of $(e^x, \tan^{-1}x)$ or from among many other series given by Euler  in Analysis.

I would like to see the common exp/log unification basis of such complex numbers played out in a generalization to the pair $(u,v)$.

$$  u^{iv(u)}+1=0 \rightarrow v(u)=\frac{\pi}{ln\,u}$$

[image: Interesting "Eulerian" Points]

Barring integer values on the $(u,v)$ graph can any number on abscissa or ordinate be expressed by means of a convergent series? If so by means of which series can they be expressed as another case.. and if they cannot be, why not?

Do identities/relations exist in complex analysis or elsewhere satisfied by such irrational point pairs?

For narrowing the discussion.. in particular we take an integer from the geometric series sum:

$$ 2 = 1+ 1/2 + 1/2^2+ 1/2^3 + 1/2^4 +.. $$

and in particular when  $v(2)= n\approx 4.53236 $

**Can we set up a convergent series for this $n\approx 4.53236?$**

Thanks in advance for all related comments.

Comment: $\log(1+z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} z^k$ gives the value of $1/v(1+z)$ for $|z| < 1$. What do you want more ? The coefficients of $\frac{z}{\log(1+z)}$ are much more complicated.

Comment: To which points on the graph do you refer ?